# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$os' (T_VARIABLE) PHP Error

Tags: php, syntax-error

I'm using the following code to try and print the operating system of the user:

Header:

```
<?php
$user_agent = getenv("HTTP_USER_AGENT");

if (strpos($user_agent, "Win") !== FALSE)
$os = "Windows"; 
else (strpos($user_agent, "Mac") !== FALSE)
$os = "Mac";
?>
```

Body:

```
<?php
if($os = "Windows")
{

}
elseif($os == "Mac")
{

} 
?>
```

I get the error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$os' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\xamppfile\htdocs\ProjectSite\includes\identifier.php on line 7

Comment: You can't put condition in else statement.

Comment: (a) Which is line 7? (b) How do you handle the case where the `$user_agent` is neither Mac nor Windows? That will lead to an undefined `$os`, won't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$user_agent = getenv("HTTP_USER_AGENT");

if (strpos($user_agent, "Win") !== FALSE) {
    $os = "Windows"; 

}
else if(strpos($user_agent, "Mac") !== FALSE) {
    $os = "Mac";
}

?>
```

Comment: this is not helpful unless you add some explanation of what the questioner was doing wrong and what your proposed code does

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have condition in else statement should use `else if` and also have practice of declaring your variable before using it,

```
$os = "";
if (strpos($user_agent, "Win") !== FALSE)
$os = "Windows"; 
else if(strpos($user_agent, "Mac") !== FALSE)
$os = "Mac";
```